# Unable to accept filenames as arguments for reading from (or writing to) a file

Tags: java, file-io

The following program is meant to read from a file:-

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class file_read
{
 private Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 private Scanner fileinput;

 public void open()            // [1]
 {
  try
  {
   String filename = input.next();
   fileinput = new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt"));     // [2]
  }          
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.println("opening error.");
  }
 }

 public void read()
 {
   // some task to read the file
 }

 public void closeFile()
 { 
   // closing the file
 }
}
```

Problem lies with [1] and I think that the statement [2] is creating the problem. If I replace the `filename+".txt"` with the actual filename, everything runs fine. I am unable to pinpoint the reason. Please help.

Comment: Do you get an Exception? Something?

Comment: Please change `catch(Exception e) { System.out.println("opening error."); }` to `catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } ` Your current error message isn't very helpful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Only the message I give as exception is printed.

Comment: Aside from what @ElliottFrisch said, just run this in a debugger and set a breakpoint on your line marked `[2]`... see what `filename` is. If it works when you specify a literal filename then obviously `filename` isn't reading in what you think it is. Just take a look at the value and figure it out.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The message is as follows:-

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`
`        at file_reader.open(file_reader.java:13)
`        at exp.main(exp.java:9)`

Comment: You're `fileName` isn't being set... verify by adding a `null` check.  `fileinput = (filename != null) ? new Scanner(new File(filename+".txt")) : null;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  The filename isn't being set. It is being assigned to `null`. I am not getting a way to avoid this. Can you help?

Comment: How many Scanner(s) of System.in have you constructed? Did you close any of them? Try `input.hasNextLine() and input.nextLine();`

Comment: I didn't close the `System.in` stream. However, I am unable to close the stream. I tried `input.close()` (naively, ofcourse) but to no avail. Also, I don't think that this stream is causing any problem.